error in firebase function 2n Gen, "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')
Im trying to switch from Firebase first gen to 2nd gen, and it already frustrated me,
this is just my code, simple
const {onDocumentCreated} = require("firebase-functions/v2/firestore");
   exports.totalGroup = onDocumentCreated(
   {region: "asia-southeast2"}, "tallyscan/{id}", async (event)=>{
      console.log("get event data");
      const snapshot = event.data();
      const id = event.params.id;
    console.log(snapshot);
    console.log(id);
  });

This the error

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')
at func (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/v2/providers/firestore.js:297:115)
at /layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/function_wrappers.js:113:25
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5

      {
         "name": "functions",
         "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
         "scripts": {
         "lint": "eslint .",
         "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
         "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
         "start": "npm run shell",
         "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
         "logs": "firebase functions:log"
           },
          "engines": {
          "node": "18"
            },
          "main": "index.js",
         "dependencies": {
         "exceljs": "^4.4.0",
         "firebase-admin": "^12.1.0",
         "firebase-functions": "^5.0.1"
          },
         "devDependencies": {
         "eslint": "^8.15.0",
         "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
         "firebase-functions-test": "^3.1.0"
          },
         "private": true
          }


Do any of your console.log statements fire?

nope, so i think something wrong in the firebase function package?

Did you figure out what is causing this? I'm running into the same issue and the really weird thing is I deploy a function it works, I add one console log to the working function and it stops working without changing anything else...
